# Is it better to mine Monero on solo mining or joining a mining pool?

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, gpu-mining, mining-hardware, solo-mining

Considering fees and profits, but also the best thing for the Monero network, which is the most valuable solution?

Also, is it depending on hardware and hashrate power?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pool.  I'd venture to say that if you are asking this, you don' have a multiple GPU rig(s).  Current difficulty/hashrate, a small rig would be extremely lucky to find a block.

Comment: I'm asking this due to making a knowledge base for the Monero's adopters. :)

Comment: "which is the most valuable solution" is odd given the question speaks of profit AND whats best for the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for sure the best thing to join a pool - unless you have a really high hash-power. If you own a data center you can go on and solo mine but in nearly any other case, it's more profitable to use a mining pool.

Apart from profitability, for the Monero network it doesn't make a big difference if you solo-mine or not.

In general, you of course need "good" hardware to get a high hash-rate. A really fast CPU or GPU is what you need. Everything else isn't significantly important. GPU mining is more profitable than CPU mining.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it would be profitable with a Dual AMD Epyc (highest grade 128 Dual-Tread Cores each) and some 256GB on RAM... Would be roughly 256 Core Treads with 1GB RAM per Core Tread... It's about investment vs. profit...