# What is the best way to help the Monero network?

Tags: mining, full-node, network, solo-mining, pool-mining

> Apart from profitability, for the Monero network it doesn't make a big
>   difference if you solo-mine or not.

This answer to [Is it better to mine Monero on solo mining or joining a mining pool?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10685/is-it-better-to-mine-monero-on-solo-mining-or-joining-a-mining-pool/10687#10687) suggested to me a new question: *which is the best way for a single user to help the Monero network?*

Running a full Monero network node?

Doing solo mining? Pool mining?

Or something different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to help the Monero both directly and indirectly.

- Run a full node to directly support the network
- Donate to the [Monero Forum Funding System](https://forum.getmonero.org/8/funding-required)
- Join a [Monero workgroup](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroCommunity/comments/8pglur/comprehensive_list_of_monero_workgroups/) for mining, support, or any others
- Participate in many of the Monero forums, such as here on the Stackexchange, on Reddit, Quora, etc
- Learn as much about Monero as you can so you can help others
- Join a local cryptocurrency/Monero meetup or start your own
- Contribute to the [Monero Ecosystem](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem) project
- Run as a solo miner or join a small pool to help decententralization aspects

You could additionally set up a mining rig, to both equalize on profits and make your hashpower of larger significance.

Answer (score 2):

Running a full node with both in and outbound connections on the p2p ports.